# Can't allow users to upload files on ASP.NET 4.0 Application

Tags: asp.net, iis, permissions

I am trying to set up a page in a .net 4.0 application where users can upload a file, but I can't seem to set up the permissions for the directory that the files should end up at to allow that. I have tried temporarily allowing everyone full access to the directory, but to no avail.

I have also tried allowing the application pool identity (Network Service) full read/write permissions to the directory, but that also didn't fix it.

I am using anonymous authentication with the user identity set as the application pool identity.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Where is the directory that you are trying to write to?  Is it part of the applications directory?  Also, what version of IIS?

Comment: have you tried using Impersonation Level to your directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try giving access to user IIS_WPG . This will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Double check if the trust level in the application is sufficient for the application to be able to perform the writes.

Giving the application full trust will do that.